# How do I find the actual binary/script using 'which' in zsh?

Tags: zsh, which

In zsh, when I enter `which git` it shows:

```
git: aliased to noglob git
```

How do I find out which git binary it actually invokes? (eg: `/usr/bin/git` vs `~/bin/git`). Basically I want to bypass the aliases when I use `which`.

Comment: Have you tried `whereis`?

Comment: @SaulOrtega Didn't know about `whereis` before. Looks like `whereis -b git` lists all the git binaries in $PATH.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `zsh`, [`which` is shorthand for `whence -c`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins), and supports other `whence` options. In particular:

```
-p   Do a path search for name even if it is an alias, 
     reserved word, shell function or builtin.
```

So:

```
$ which  git  
git: aliased to noglob git
$ which -p git
/usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 /usr/bin/which git
```

it should give you some file path, probably `/usr/bin/git`